# Subtracting an unknown interval from a datetime

Tags: c#, date, time, automation

I am setting up a system to gather data from a database based on a user inputted start date and end date. The system will gather data averaged over an interval(1 hour, 6 hours, or one day for example). If the user does not input a start or end date I would like the program to set the start date to the current time minus the interval.

I currently have the user inputting the interval in the following format.

```
1m = 1 minute
1h = 1 hour
12h = 12 hours
3d = 3 days
```

So these values are not formatted like datetime. I could take the current datetime and subtract it by either minutes, hours, or days depending on the value appended (splitting on the number), but this would mean many `if` statements. What I would really like is a method to subtract a datetime by an arbitrary value Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Is your application a windows form?

Comment: Look up the various `FromXxx` static methods on the `TimeSpan` type.  You can say `DateTime.Now-TimeSpan.FromHours(12)` and get a time twelve hours ago

Comment: Hey Flydog, that is an option but would mean I'd have to write out if statements for minutes, hours, and days.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing predefined time intervals (that are implemented e. g. via a separate type/enum), it is much easier to let the user freely specify a `TimeSpan`.

This has two advantages:

1. The user is not restricted to predefined intervals
2. You can subtract the `TimeSpan` directly from your `DateTime.Now`

If restriction to limited intervals is a requirement, you can implement this in the view/window. But still this should be a TimeSpan.